# Нахождение кратчайшего пути в матрице

Tags: java, алгоритм

Есть города А, B, C, D, E, F, G. В таблице указаны цены на билеты из (горизонтальная ось) в (вертикальная ось).  Если из города в этот же город - то не нужно - цена 0; 
Если такого рейса нет - то значение -1.  Найти самый дешевый путь из точки А в точку В.

```
0   10  5   3   20  7   100 
10  0   7   10  20  7   -1 
20  10  0   250 10  7   5 
10  20  6   0   8   10  2 
3   150 -1  6   0   7   2 
8   200 5   50  40  0   20 
120 7   -1  -1  -1  50  0
```

Comment: боюсь алгоритм к языку (в том числе java) не имеет ничего общего. сначала вам надо разобратся в самом алгоритме, а когда возникнут проблемы с реализацией на java тогда и обращайтесь.

Answer (score 8):

Алгоритм Дейкстры